# Spring mvc binding exception on submitting select box

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a JSP which has country, state and city drop down box. City is by default populated and then state and city will come based on country and state selected using ajax.

```
 <form:select path="ContactInfoVO[0].countryList" multiple="single" id="country">       
<form:option value="-1" label="-- Select Country--"></form:option>                      
<c:forEach var="country" items="${ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO[0].countryList}" varStatus="item">
<form:option value="${country.countryId}" label="${country.countryName}"/></c:forEach> </form:select>   

<form:select path="ContactInfoVO[0].stateList" multiple="single" id="state" class="small">      
<form:option value="-1" label="-- Select State--"></form:option>                        
<c:forEach var="state" items="${ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO[0].stateList}" varStatus="item">
<form:option value="${state.stateId}" label="${state.stateName}"/></c:forEach></form:select>    

<form:select path="ContactInfoVO[0].cityList" multiple="single" id="city" class="validate[required] small">     
<form:option value="-1" label="-- Select City--"></form:option>                     
<c:forEach var="city" items="${ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO[0].cityList}" varStatus="item">
<form:option value="${city.cityId}" label="${city.cityName}"/></c:forEach></form:select>
```

When i submit this form, i am getting error -

```
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
    Field error in object 'ManagerVO' on field 'ContactInfoVO[0].cityList': rejected value [80930]; codes [typeMismatch.ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO[0].cityList,typeMismatch.ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO.cityList,typeMismatch.ContactInfoVO[0].cityList,typeMismatch.ContactInfoVO.cityList,typeMismatch.cityList,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO[0].cityList,ContactInfoVO[0].cityList]; arguments []; default message [ContactInfoVO[0].cityList]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'ContactInfoVO[0].cityList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.admin.command.CityVO] for property 'cityList[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    Field error in object 'ManagerVO' on field 'ContactInfoVO[0].countryList': rejected value [31]; codes [typeMismatch.ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO[0].countryList,typeMismatch.ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO.countryList,typeMismatch.ContactInfoVO[0].countryList,typeMismatch.ContactInfoVO.countryList,typeMismatch.countryList,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO[0].countryList,ContactInfoVO[0].countryList]; arguments []; default message [ContactInfoVO[0].countryList]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'ContactInfoVO[0].countryList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.admin.command.CountryVO] for property 'countryList[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    Field error in object 'ManagerVO' on field 'ContactInfoVO[0].stateList': rejected value [601]; codes [typeMismatch.ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO[0].stateList,typeMismatch.ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO.stateList,typeMismatch.ContactInfoVO[0].stateList,typeMismatch.ContactInfoVO.stateList,typeMismatch.stateList,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO[0].stateList,ContactInfoVO[0].stateList]; arguments []; default message [ContactInfoVO[0].stateList]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'ContactInfoVO[0].stateList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.admin.command.StateVO] for property 'stateList[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is there in the output: you are trying to set your domain class field `ContactInfoVO[0].cityList` that has type `List` with a `String` value.

Without seeing the code for your domain classes, etc., its hard to know what your page is intending to do. If you are trying to populate your database with a single value determined by the user, then its common to populate the select dropdown with values from a different table (or class/enum) and then set the single value selected by the user into its own class/table. It looks like you are trying to do both things with the same class.

Comment: I am just trying to populate city on the basis of state and country, on form submission i will be using only cityId. All three fields(country, state, city) has there own master tables from where select box are being populated. Now when i click on submit, spring raise this error even before reaching to controller, that means binding of the model attribute is failing. Can you suggest me something so that i can get only cityId on my controller?

Comment: I think you need to change `<form:select path="ContactInfoVO[0].cityList">` to bind to a different path. One that takes a `String` value, not a `List`. ContactInfoVO[0].cityList expects a List and you are trying to set it to a String. So it seems like you are trying to set cityId back to your master list, not the table where you want the data saved.

Comment: Thanks, don't know how i didn't notice this earlier :( but this fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying set (for example) a countryId to ContactInfoVO[0].countryList. So you are setting an Integer to a List.

I think the problem is in here:

```
 <form:select path="ContactInfoVO[0].countryList" multiple="single" id="country">
```

I don't see a `countryList` there make any sense. It should be rather like `ContactInfo[0].countryId` which matches what you select, in this case `"${country.countryId}"`

It will be more clear if your post ContractInfoVO class and your  tag.